# R codes for variation of information criterion using “mclust”

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am developing model-based clustering.

First, I developed model-based clustering in R using "mclust." Next, I wanted to take 75% of the sample, re-run model-based clustering and compare the results with the results from the entire dataset using variation of information or rand index. However, I am getting stuck with the codes.

Here are the codes made available for variation of information on CRAN.

```
cl1 <-sample(1:30, 10, replace=TRUE)
cl2 <- c(cl1[1:5], sample(1:3, 5, replace=TRUE))
vi.dist(cl1,cl2)
vi.dist(cl1,cl2, parts=TRUE)
```

Here is how I developed my clustering solutions:

```
model <-Mclust(data[,18:22])
```

model based clustering solution using entire dataset and data is the name of my dataset using columns 18 to 22

```
random <- data[rbinom(nrow(data), 1,.75)==1,]
```

developed a random sample

```
randommodel <-Mclust(random[,18:22])
```

model-based clustering using the random sample

```
cl1 <- (model$classification)
cl2 <- (randommodel$classification)
vi.dist(cl1,cl2)
```

my attempt at variation of information using R codes, result failed because cl1 and cl2 are not the same length.

So, how do I make the two solutions the same length given that the two solutions have a different number of observations? Or, am I trying to use variation of information incorrectly?

Comment: According to the docs, `vi.dist` "Computes the 'variation of information' distance of Meila (2007) between two clusterings/partitions of the same objects." Right now, you're using different objects, not the same objects. `vi.dist` makes sense when you use two different clustering methods on the same observations; not the same method on different sets of observations.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I was trying to replicate the results of the following article, see page 486: Mun, E. Y., von Eye, A., Bates, M. E., & Vaschillo, E. G. (2008). Finding groups using model-based cluster analysis: Heterogeneous emotional self-regulatory processes and heavy alcohol use risk. Developmental Psychology, 44, 481–495. doi:10.1037/0012-1649.44.2.481

Comment: Advice on statistical methods is off topic for this site. You may wish to post on [stats.se] if you need statistical advice.